# UITableView single-gesture row swipe actions

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to implement single-gesture swiping actions in my UITableView, where you swipe to reveal action buttons, and continue swiping all the way across to activate the default action (such as "Delete" or "Mark as Read" in Mail).

I'm implementing `-tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:` in my delegate. My button appears, and it works when I tap it, but it doesn't get activated by a full swipe.

I've tried it with and without `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` in my data source. Only the latter gets called, but neither seems to make a difference.

Is there something more I need to do? Or is this behavior not actually achievable using the standard API?

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if the swipe has past a certain threshold in your gesture recognizer's target function.

Try this

```
func swipeRight(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    let threshold : CGFloat = 100;
    var startLocation = CGPoint()
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){
        startLocation = sender.locationInView(self.view)
    }else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended){
        let stopLocation = sender.locationInView(self.view)
        let distanceX = stopLocation.x - startLocation.x
        let distanceY = stopLocation.y - startLocation.y
        let distance = sqrt(distanceX*distanceX + distanceY*distanceY )
        if (distance > threshold ){
            //Delete or Edit Row Here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be if I were doing a custom implementation for the swipe buttons. Actually, I am doing that (based on MGSwipeTableCell), but I'm trying to see if I can replace that approach with the standard API and get rid of a lot of code. Using `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`, the OS takes care of the gesture recognizer entirely.